# How to increase duration of content-assist popup in eclipse kepler?

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

For some unknown reason, the duration of the popup window for the control assist proposals has been shortened. If my proposals contain a list long enough to scroll the suggestions, the popup auto-hides in the midst of scrolling.

I tried deleting the `.metadata` folder of my workspace and restarted but it didn't work.

Could someone please help regarding the same?

I am using Eclipse Kepler.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjest the content assist delay in eclipse preference.
Refer this [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2013/05/30/eclipse-papercut-13-reduce-delay-in-code-completion/).

Comment: That setting is the delay _before_ the popup triggers. My issue is with the duration it stays _after_ it appears

Comment: After contest assist opens up press `F2` key to make it sticky. Then you can use mouse wheel or keyboard down arrow key or scroll thumb on the right side  to scroll the list.